# JAXB marshall/unmarshall objects defined by plugins

Tags: java, jaxb

Let's suppose the following scenario:

I have a list of objects of the following type:

```java
public class MyObject {
   private String name
   private SomeClass someField
   private List<Fact> facts
}
```

The fields `name` and `someField` are just to show that the class has some regular members. You can suppose that it's known how to convert these classes to xml.

`Fact` is an interface where the implementations are not known to me but provided by plugins. Plugins can be required to provide arbitrary code, but I would like to make it as simple as possible.

I want to save and load these objects to xml. Note that while loading the xml, not all implementations may be present (the xml might have been written with a different set of plugins). I want to be able to still read the xml and not lose any information when saving again. In other words: I'm willing add a field such as `List<Element>` or `List<String>` to the class and when reading the xml, all parts where a plugin is present should be read into the corresponding `Fact`s, while all parts without a plugin should be stored in an `Element` or `String` and when saving again, both lists get saved and could be read by a program having all plugins.

How best to achieve this using JAXB?

One way I can see is to use `Map<Class, org.w3c.dom.Element>` instead of `List<Fact>` which can be converted to xml by JaxB and then let any plugin provide custom code converting from and to "their" element using the `org.w3c.dom` API, but using that API is somewhat cumbersome, so I wonder whether there is a better way?

Comment: Tell us what have you tried so far, what was result, what was good, what is the remaining problem.

Comment: @metallurg: But I did: In the last paragraph - I even say why I don't like that solution. I can of course provide some approximate code if it helps understanding the scenario, but my trouble is not finding "a" solution, I'm searching for a JAXB-idiomatic solution at best that provides a simple client interface. If anyone can give some pointers, I'd also be happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea about `best`, but one approach that comes close to what you describe is this:

JAXB doesn't work with interfaces; best it can do would be an abstract class. Meaning you need to use `List<Object>` or `List<AbstractFact>`. (but you can enforce some restriction in the getter, pluginresolver or afterUnmarshall()).

Your plugin provides the basic classes for the extension (SPI would be the usual approach). You collect them and (after validation) use them to create your `JAXBContext`. (If you want to support multiple interfaces, maybe provide them by different methods).

In the xml you need to have a type marker like this: `<fact xsi:type=\"aFact\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">`. If you create the xml with jaxb it will be created autmatically. (The classes need to have the @XmlRootElement annotation).

Here is a stripped down example:

```
interface Fact {

}
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
class R {

    @XmlElement(name = "fact")
    private List<Object> facts;


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Fact> getTest() {
        if (facts == null) {
            facts = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return (List<Fact>) (Object) facts;
    }

    public void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent) {
        // check if all facts implement same interface
        for(Object object:facts) {
            if (!(object instanceof Fact)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported type in facts list");
            }
        }
    }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "aFact")
class AFact implements Fact {

    @XmlElement
    private String a;

    public AFact() {
    }

    public AFact(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AFact [a=" + a + "]";
    }

}

public class Jax {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

        String xml = "<r><fact xsi:type=\"aFact\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><a>ba</a></fact></r>";

        List<Class<?>> contextClasses = new ArrayList<>();
        contextClasses.add(R.class);
        contextClasses.addAll(getClassesFromPlugin());
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(contextClasses.toArray(new Class<?>[0]));
        R entity = (R) context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));

        System.out.println(entity.getTest());

        R r = new R();
        r.getTest().add(new AFact("ab"));

        context.createMarshaller().marshal(r, System.out);
    }

    private static List<Class<?>> getClassesFromPlugin() {
        List<Class<?>> asList = Arrays.asList(AFact.class);
        for(Class<?> cls:asList) {
            if (!Fact.class.isAssignableFrom(cls)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported class");
            }
        }
        return asList;
    }
}
```